# Finding elements: different syntax -> different results - Explanation needed

Tags: cypress

When I use:
`cy.get('b').contains('xdz') // find 1 element`

but when I use:
`cy.get('b:contains("xdz")') // find 2 elements`

Can someone explain me what is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contains('xdz')` is a cypress command which always yields only the first element containing the text. You can read more about it from this [Github Thread](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1009).

`:contains("xdz")` is a Jquery command and it returns all elements containing the text. You can read more about it from the [Jquery Docs](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/).

Answer (score 3):

`cy.get('b').contains('xdz')` is invoking a Cypress command, which is designed to only return a single element. This is by design so that you can narrow a search by text content.

`cy.get('b:contains("xdz")')` is using a jquery pseudo-selector `:contains()` to test the text inside element `<b>` and is designed to return all matching elements.

Pseudo-selectors are extensions to the CSS selector syntax that apply jQuery methods during the selection. In this case `:contains(sometext)` is shorthand for `$el.text().contains('sometext')`. Becuase it's part of the selector, it returns all matching elements.

It's worth while understanding jquery selector variations, as this example illustrates - it can give you different results for different situations.